# Why does the imaginary part disappear when you take the magnitude square of a complex number?

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I am looking at the following example problem dealing with complex numbers:

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }\left | e^{-4t +j\frac{\pi }{4}} \right |^{2}dt$$

In this example when you take the magnitude square of a complex the integral becomes:

$$\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{-8t} dt$$

I am not understanding how the imaginary part disappears when you take the magnitude square of a complex number. I understand that $j^2$ = -1 but it doesn't make sense how the imaginary part goes away. Any assistance in understanding this step is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does "magnitude" mean to you in the context of complex numbers?

Comment: We measure stuff in terms of real numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For real $a,b$ we have

$$|e^{a+jb}|=|e^ae^{jb}|=e^a|e^{jb}|=e^a,$$

since $|e^{jb}|=1.$

Answer (score 3):

By definition, if $z$ is a complex number then $|z|$ is its distance in the complex plane from $0$. This distance is a non-negative real number since it is just the length of some line segment. Its square is also a non-negative real number.